# Does Hibernate Search load entity associations and can I mix free text queries with native SQL?

Tags: hibernate-search

```
package example;
...

@Entity
@Indexed
public class Book {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

@Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
private String title;

@Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
private String subtitle; 
@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.NO, store = Store.YES)
@DateBridge(resolution = Resolution.DAY)
private Date publicationDate;

@IndexedEmbedded
@ManyToMany 
private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<Author>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy="book")
List<BookPages> bookPages;

}
```

1) If the search result is of type Book.class does the result contain @ManyToOne objects (bookPages) or do I have to load them separately? Because I need them for showing the result.

2) Is it possible to add a native sql clause to the search? Because I need to limit the result and for that I have to JOIN another table which is not declared in Book.class.

Answer (score 1):

1. That is a basic Hibernate ORM question, not related to Hibernate Search. Yes you can always navigate from one entity to its relations by just invoking the getter / accessing the fields: depending on your (configurable) fetch strategy it will either have the relation preloaded in "one shot" when loading the main entity (likely with a JOIN) or fetch it transparently on demand. This configuration is however not have any effect on functionality, more a performance tuning option.
2. No you can't mix SQL with an Hibernate Search (Fulltext) query; what you can do is to expose the needed data from the other table in the mapping - which would be a cleaner mapping anyway - and then use the Hibernate Search annotations to make sure all fields you need are indexed as well, so that you can include the restrictions in the FullTextQuery directly; fill perform much faster as well than any SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 1) Good to know that related entities will be accessible depending on the general fetching strategy. 2) This will not to be easy because the "rights" are in no direct relation to the indexed entity (have to join 2 tables - not my database model just have to work with it).

Comment: Even if it's not your database, remember Hibernate can go quite far with mapping tricks. You can have a column mapped to a @Formula, or you can map your entities on a view (for example - not sure if it applies). You mentioned "rights": consider as well using Filters as described in the Search reference: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#query-filter . A Filter can be "expensive" to prepare (like using SQL queries) but is then cacheable and applied to multiple queries.

Comment: Yeah 'Formula' would be a choice. Can I add a @Formula fiel to the index?

Comment: Of course you can add a @Forumla field. Hibernate Search won't even know if it's any different.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to  mix native SQL with hibernate search query, as there is no way to intersect the results from both queries without iterating on at least one of the results.

See the documentation reference about this exact question.
[Hibernate Search - FAQ - Can I mix HQL and Lucene queries?](http://hibernate.org/search/faq/)
http://hibernate.org/search/faq/